# Views Slideshow gives duplicate row classes

Tags: theming, views

I use views_slideshow and I use it's option Items Per Slide and I set it to 2, so it shows two nodes at a time. Problem is now, I cannot give both nodes separate styling, i.e. I want first row to have padding to right and second row to have padding to left, I could do that if it didn't have identical row-number classes:

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily achieve what you need with a small workaround using css pseudo classes `:first-child` and `:last-child`, apply them to the surrounding div and easily get the paddings for first and last elements. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp).

Comment: Does this support IE8?

Comment: First-child yes, last-child no. But in your case since there are 2 elements only, you can do padding on all rows an then override it for the first one.